# why do we need the other continuous distributions if everything is just converging to normal distributions

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution

today my teacher asked why do we need the other continuous distributions if everything is just converging to normal distributions when n is greater or equal to 30. I may partly understand the question but I want to understand it well.

Comment: "everything is just converging to normal distributions when n is greater or equal to 30" Here's a hint: it is not the case that *everything* converges to normal distributions when n is at least 30. Have a try at restating this more precisely. What is it that converges to the normal distribution?

Comment: Why do we need numbers when everything just converges to zero? ;-)

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to Central Limit Theorem, note that it has conditions as well (i.e. finite mean and variance). For example, sum/mean of Cauchy distributed RVs doesn't converge to normal distribution.

Also, the following question that's posed by your teacher needs context. Other distributions have very well use cases, too.

> why do we need the other continuous distributions

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher appears to be alluding [a common misinterpretation of the central limit theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473455/debunking-wrong-clt-statement).

The central limit theorem concerns the convergence of $
\dfrac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}
$, not of the data themselves.

Under mild conditions that are likely to be met in an introductory statistics class, as the sample size $n$ gets large (maybe $30$ is enough, maybe you need $30$ trillion bazillion), the sample distribution converges to the population distribution. This is the [Glivenko–Cantelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem).

In other words, by Glivenko–Cantelli, as we get a larger and larger sample size, we get a better and better representation of the population.

Comment: Your teacher also mentioned about continuous distributions, but the central limit theorem applies to discrete distributions, too!