# Does a Binomial converge to Poisson or Normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, convergence, central-limit-theorem

I have read the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873825/binomial-distribution-approaches-to-poisson-or-normal#:%7E:text=If%20n%E2%86%92%E2%88%9E%20and,distribution%20with%20expected%20value%20%CE%BB.). Here the distinction is that

- If $n\to\infty$ and $p\to0$ while $np$ approaches some positive number $\lambda,$ then the binomial distribution approaches a Poisson distribution with expected value $\lambda.$
- If $n\to\infty$ as $p$ stays fixed, and $X\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)$ then the distribution of $(X-np)/\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ approaches the standard normal distribution, i.e. the normal distribution with expected value $0$ and standard deviation $1.$

I am finding it hard to wrap my head around this. In the derivation of the central limit theorem nowhere is $p$ taken into consideration. So even if $p$ is very small, according to CLT the standardized Binomial should limit to a standard normal. And the two limiting behaviors are both for $n \to \infty$
Please help me understand this concept a bit more. How can CLT not be valid when $p$ is really small?

Comment: On first pass, my instinct is that ambiguity arises here due to insufficient precision in how the semantics of "approaches" is interpreted mathematically.

Comment: The answer you reference clearly articulates the fundamental point, beginning with "It is sloppy to say something approaches something depending on n as n→∞, unless it is precisely defined and not meant literally...."

Comment: You appear to be making a common mistake about the central limit theorem: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473455/debunking-wrong-clt-statement. The central limit theorem is about a sampling distribution, not about the original population.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difficulty disappears when you are careful in formulating the limits. In the first case, $p$ **is not constant**, so it would be more precise to write it as $p_n$, as $p$ varies with $n$. We can write $n \cdot p_n \to \lambda>0$ another way as $p_n \sim \lambda/n$, where $\sim$ means that the quotient between the two sides converges to unity with $n \to\infty$.

For the second case, $p$ is constant, and however small, when $n$ is large enough, $np$ is no longer small. The CLT is still valid when $p>0$ is small and constant.

To understand this better, you could try to use the CLT for IID variables in the first case. Write the binomial out as a sum of $n$ IID Bernoulli variables, as $X_n= B_1 + \dotsm + B_n$. Now **check the assumptions of the [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)**. You will find that the $B_1, B_2, \dotso, B_n$ all must have the same distribution, **and that distribution should not depend on $n$**. Is that the case?

Comment: If np is small but not infinitesimal (smaller than 4), the binomial distribution is asymmetrical. Even if n very very large I don't understand how it'll look like bell curve. So my question is why CLT fails here?

Comment: @AhmedAbdullah: If $n$ is large and $np$ is, say 4 or 2 or 1 ... then the Poisson fit better than the normal. The CLT does not fail, but willl maybe need a very large $n$

Answer (score 1):

One can write the CLT as:
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,1)
$$

If we consider each $X_i$ here as a Bernoulli random variable that are independent and **identically distributed**, recalling that the mean and variance of a Bernoulli random variable are $p$ and $p(1-p)$ respectively, we can rewrite this as

$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,1)
$$

And then note that a binomial is simply a sum of n Bernoulli random variable. That is that for  $X = X_1 + \dots + X_n$ where each $X_i \sim Bernoulli(p)$ we have  $X \sim Binomial(n,p)$. So we can finally get the form of the CLT given in your question.

$$
\frac{X - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,1)
$$

This is true even when p is very small, **so long as the bernoulli random variables are identically distributed**. In the first case where the binomial converges to a poisson distribution, p is growing smaller as n goes to infinity, and so the requirement that the random variables be identically distributed is not satisfied.