# Under what constraints , if any, does the binomial distribution become equal to the normal distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

I understand that when n approaches infinity binomial distribution also approaches a Poisson distribution. What about the normal distribution? I googled and found that if n approaches infinity and p and q are large (not close to either 1 or 0) then it follows a normal distribution. But if p is large np should also be infinite. So it seems to me that normal distribution can only approximate the binomial distribution when n, p, and q all are finite. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: "if p is large np should also be infinite"—why do you believe that?

Comment: let's say p=0.1, if n is infinite then n*0.1 = infinite

Comment: What if $p$ approaches zero as $n$ approaches infinity?

Comment: Nobody's saying that $n$ is infinite. It's _approaching_ infinity, in the limit.

Comment: @Dave In that case, what is the difference between the  Poisson and the normal?

Comment: You might want to look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519029/does-a-binomial-converge-to-poisson-or-normal

Comment: @Henry I have looked at the question you have mentioned. If np is small but not infinitesimal  (smaller than 4),  the binomial distribution is  asymmetrical. Even if n very very large I don't understand how it'll look like bell curve. So my question is why CLT fails here?

Comment: Also relevant ... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90422/poisson-vs-binomial-for-rare-events

Comment: Your reasoning is fundamentally flawed. "It" has multiple meanings here, because you are asking about two (radically) different sequences of random variables.  In the first case the properties of those variables *change* with $n,$ whereas in the second case (Central Limit Theorem) the properties *remain fixed.*  The moral here is that it's crucial to learn the context and assumptions that lead to any general conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, normal approximations have been used to
to get serviceable answers to such problems as finding
$P(X \le 7),$ where $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 30, p = 1/6).$
Extensive tables of binomial CDFs are relatively rare, and using the binomial PDF formula to find the necessary eight terms
seems excessively tedious.

Several rules of thumb have been proposed to limit the use
of normal approximations to situations in which something like two place accuracy is possible. One of the most common
guidelines is that $\min[np, n(1-p)] \ge 5,$ which helps to
ensure that the approximating normal distribution puts most of its probability on $(0,n).$ It is not always mentioned that approximations tend to be best if $p$ is near $1/2,$ so that the binomial distribution
is nearly symmetrical.

The normal approximation for the specific problem above is
as follows:

$$P(X \le 7) = P(X < 7.5) =
P\left( 
\frac{X-np} { \sqrt{np(1-p)} } < 
\frac{7.5 - 5}{ \sqrt{25/6} }
= 1.225\right)\\ \approx P(Z < 1.225) = 0.8897,$$

where $Z$ is standard normal, the first step is known as a continuity correction,
and the last would require interpolation, using most
printed standard normal CDF tables.

In R, an exact computation is simply $P(X \le 7) = 0.8863.$

```
pbinom(7, 30, 1/6)
[1] 0.8863132
```

In the figure below, the exact probability is the sum of the
heights of the vertical bars to the left of the dotted
vertical line. The normal approximation is the area
under the density curve to the left of that line.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
x = 0:30;  pdf = dbinom(x, 30, 1/6)
hdr = "BINOM(30, 1/6) with Normal Approx"
plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=3, col="blue", main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=7.5, col="orange", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
curve(dnorm(x, 5, sqrt(25/6)), add=T, lwd=2, col="brown")
```

*Note:* A Poisson approximation to a binomial probability is often useful when $n$ is large and the Poisson mean $\mu = np$ is of moderate size. In the current example, $n$ is not large enough for a good Poisson approximation. $P(Y \le 7) = 0.8666$, where $Y\sim\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 5).$

```
ppois(7, 5)
[1] 0.8666283
k = 0:7;  sum(exp(-5)*5^k/factorial(k))
[1] 0.8666283
```