# paired data large samples

Tags: normality-assumption, paired-data

When comparing the means of matched data and large samples are taken, the differences must be Normally distributed in the population. True/False

The answer that was given in class was that it was false and i cannot understand why, I thought since the sample data was large the central limit theorem would apply and therefore the differences are normally distributed.

Comment: You seem to be agreeing with the answer!  Notice that "Normally distributed in the populations" and "differences are normally distributed" mean two different things.

Comment: Of likely interest: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473455/debunking-wrong-clt-statement. You appear to be making the (common) mistake that some of my colleagues made last summer.