# How can the CLT fix OLS regression residuals that are not normally distributed?

Tags: regression, residuals, central-limit-theorem

I often hear that when the residuals depart from normality, the central limit theorem can be used to fix things. I do not quite understand how this works, since the central limit theorem is a statement about scaled sums of random variables. How exactly is the CLT used to make the data normal?

Comment: You appear to have a common misconception about the central limit theorem: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473455/debunking-wrong-clt-statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CLT does not make the data normal. For OLS the CLT is a result about the regression parameters. Indeed, they are expressed as a sum of random variables.

Comment: I read something about the residuals being able to be thought of as the sum of independent errors, does that make sense?

Comment: Not really, the residuals are $Y-\hat{Y}$, so you can think of them as a *sum*, but they don't tend to normal as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I read somewhere that Gauss (*the* Gauss) had an interesting (but incorrect) argument as to why regression residuals should be normal.  Even the giants make mistakes.

Comment: @BigBendRegion better provide a source!

Comment: See here, bottom of p. 64.  http://pzs.dstu.dp.ua/DataMining/mls/bibl/Gauss2Kalman.pdf

Comment: @BigBendRegion Thank you! Gauss wasn't wrong here. This touches on a different issue. Gauss's argument for the normality of errors was an assumption is his astronomical predictions paper, in that it was the result of possibly hundreds of *unobserved* variables contributing to a (seemingly) random error. Gauss didn't believe in intrinsic randomness (nor did Einstein, hence the schism between mechanical and quantum physics). OP's question seems to be an eggcorn of this; where non-normal (observed) residuals are somehow remedied by big data.

Comment: Here is another excellent answer from the past: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29731/regression-when-the-ols-residuals-are-not-normally-distributed

Comment: @AdamO I agree that Gauss was not wrong as the OP suggests, in that a larger sample size of the existing data set somehow justifies normality. On the other hand, and maybe this is too narrow a point, but if Gauss really argued that the density was precisely, mathematically normal, then he indeed was wrong, even given the astronomical context.  Yes, there were caveats about extremes, but I did not see any such caveats about the rest of the distribution.  Maybe it is in the original paper.  All that I would need would be the word "approximation" as regards the central portion.