# Checking normality without raw data

Tags: normality-assumption

Is there any way to check normality assumption only based on mean, SD and sample size? We don't have raw data.

Comment: Why do you want to check for normality?

Answer (score 4):

**NO**

Consider that $X\sim N(1, 1)$ and $Y\sim \exp(1)$ have the same mean and standard deviation, and it becomes easy to see that you need more than those values. Sample size does not help, and it sounds like you might have a [common misconception about the central limit theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473455/debunking-wrong-clt-statement) if you suspect that it would.